# CSS background position parallax offset using jQuery

Tags: jquery, parallax

I got this working but I can't set the background image to align top in div as start position, also it moves too much and too fast. How do I change the code to achieve this?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var x = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#wrapperhead1').css('background-position', '100% ' + parseInt(-x / 1) + 'px' + ', 0% ' + parseInt(-x / 2) + 'px, center top');
});
```